# inject extra element into jsx after last element of array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsx

How to render 'd' to below arrays?

```
const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    {['a', 'b', 'c'].map((o, i) => {
      return (<div>{o}</div>)
    }
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Says I will assign `['a', 'b', 'c']` to `const x` how can I use map and render new element after `c`? I can get last element like

```
{
    if(i === x.length - 1) { return('d') }
}
```

but c will be gone, how to create the 4th element?

Comment: Any particular reason this must be done from inside the map? Can't you just print `d` after the map?

Answer (score 1):

You can return both items in an array from the map callback:

```js
const x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const App = () => (
  <div>
    {x.map((o, i) => {
      if(i === x.length - 1) {
        return [
          <div key={i}>{o}</div>,
          <div key={i + 1}>d</div>
        ];
      }
      
      return (<div key={i}>{o}</div>)
    }
    )}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  app
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

However, since you always add d to the end, you can just stick the tag after the loop:

```js
const x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const App = () => (
  <div>
    {x.map((o, i) => {      
      return (<div key={i}>{o}</div>)
    }
    )}
    
    <div>d</div>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  app
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Could probably replace `[].concat` with `[...x.map` since you're using spread anyway

Comment: @CodingIntrigue - just spreading doesn't flatten an array of arrays, but it turns out that react does that automatically. This means we can skip the spread, and the concat. See updated code.